# Is it a bad practice to mix functions of <windows.h> with other classes?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning C++ on my own and, as a practice, i'm doing a very basic Version Control System (very very basic).

**I am working on Windows 10, and with gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0 (-std=c++17)**.

I have been checking the Microsoft documentation because i'm working with **`<windows.h>`**. I have been able to implement some interesting things, so the project is already taking shape; however, i'm currently trying to create, write and read files, this is something i've done before using **`<fstream>`**, but i also know that this can be done with the **`<windows.h>`** functions .

So ... What if i create the file with the **`CreateFile()`** function but write and read its data using **`ifstream`** / **`ofstream`**. Is this a bad practice? Can it cause efficiency problems? One is better than another? It just doesn't matter?

Well, the project continues :) and i'm mixing **`<windows.h>`** for creating files, and **`<fstream>`** for reading / writing, however, i'm very interested to know if this is recommended, or if it is a bad practice.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to use `<fstream>` to read/write data, then you should also use it for creating/opening files, too. There is no standard way to mix `CreateFile()` with the `std::(i|o)fstream` classes. But on Windows, `std::(i|o)fstream` will ultimately use `CreateFile()` internally for you, so there is no need to use `CreateFile()` directly, unless you really need to fine-tune its parameters.  In which case, you are likely going to end up having to create a custom `std::basic_filebuf` class that you can hand a manual `HANDLE` to, and then you can hand that class to `std::(i|o)fstream`

Comment: It is usually best to stick to standard C++ (or cross-platform libraries like boost) instead of directly calling OS-level APIs unless the functionality you need is not provided by said libraries. In particular, if all you you want from `CreateFile` is to create a file to which you can later write or read using streams, chances are, C++ streams would be enough for you, and `CreateFile` function will not be needed.

Comment: If you're using a C++ 17 or later compiler, you can use the functions in  [<filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) instead of the OS specific functions for file handling.

Comment: Avoid mixing the APIs. There is no reason to do so. Most probably, the standard implementation rests on the Windows functions, but the overhead should be negligible.

Comment: It's not harmful to your program, the only issue is that using OS-specific calls will make it harder to run the program in a different operating system

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback!. Well, it seems unanimous that it is preferable not to use OS APIs unless there is no other options, and after reading your answers it seems to be the most logical thing, I'm rewriting the code using std::filesystem, it seems simpler and more direct, however I am having problems with finding information on how to create a folder and modify its attributes to make it hidden. I think for that specific detail I must use <windows.h>. ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Comment: You should be able to use the `std::filesystem` library.

Comment: @JulioZaravia You can probably create a folder using [create_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), but setting a file as hidden is specific to `Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to stick to standard C++ where you can; that is, only use Windows-specific API calls to the extent that you need to.

You do not need to call CreateFile(...) to write to a file, so don't. The implementation of the standard library will be in terms of Win32 API calls where it needs to be anyway, so there is no performance hit in not using using a call like CreateFile(...) in that you *are* using it, just in a way that is portable due to the work done by whoever implemented the standard library.

All things being equal try to keep your usage of Win32 segregated into particular translation units (i.e. cpp files) as much as you can. Do as much as you can with standard C++. Your current project may never need to be cross-platform or share code with a cross-platform application but these are still good habits to get into. It serves no purpose to make things intentionally not portable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. Yes, i know i don't need to create a file to read / write to a file. But, it happens that my application creates directories and in each new directory it adds a text file where it immediately writes some values. This is why I was mixing the ```CreateFile()``` of ```<windows.h>``` with the write function of ```<fstream>```, however after reading the comments I have modified the code to use the ```std::filesystem``` library for directory creation, and I plan to use an instance of the ```ofstream``` class to create the text file inside the directory (and write on it).

Comment: *"You do not need to call CreateFile(...)"* - That's only true starting with C++17. Prior to that there was no way to reliably open an `fstream` in C++ on Windows.